# Parse standard input in python and convert the data into list/dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, stdin

The input to the program is as below:

```
planes
eti~A320~1~2001-2002~Boeing
swi~A210~1~2001-2002~fairchild
passenger
B23~Mr.A
D85~Ms.B
C276~Master.C
travel
eti~1~2001-2002~Mr.A~120$
eti~1~2001-2002~Ms.B~100$
eti~1~2001-2002~Ms.B~80$$
eti~1~2001-2002~Master.C~50$
swi~1~2001-2002~Mr.A~70$
swi~1~2001-2002~MS.B~90$
End

output
B23~Mr.A~95$
D85~Ms.B~90$
C276~Master.C~50$
```

I have tried to read input as below but unable to do so and even stuck on how to proceed. Do I store data in a list? If I store data in a list how do I compare using passenger id and get their average travel price?

```
import sys

list_of_lists = []

while True:
     input_ = input
     list_of_lists = (line.strip().split('\~') for line in input_)
     if input_ == 'EndOfInput':
         break
     print (input_)
     sys.stdout.write(input_)
```

Comment: `input_ = input` => `input_ = input()` for starters

Comment: you're not calling `input` function, you're copying the reference of the function in another variable.

Comment: besides: `list_of_lists = (line.strip().split('\~') for line in input_)` won't create a list, it's a generator comprehension; Do `list_of_lists = [line.strip().split('\~') for line in input_]`

Comment: and no need to escape `~`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i'm using Rodeo IDE and when i made the corrections and ran the code list_of_lists does not show any value and neither does input_ is there a different approach to the problem i am unable to define an algorithm or an approach to solve it